# change "Character set of the file:" file on update Query

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I try to import csv file using my sql Query

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'switchs_svr_primary_20170405_104805.csv' INTO TABLE switchs_svr_primary_btl
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
 IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Above Query is working fine  but in my csv file in one column British pound is exist. When csv file is loaded into a database, the "£" sign is displayed as "?"

I have try to import file using database import option:

When i import csv file to database with the default **Character set of the file** is **utf8** then , the "**£**" sign is displayed as "**?**".
But when i change  Character set of the file **utf8** to  **iso-8859-1** then , the "**£**" sign is displayed as "**£**". 
So **iso-8859-1**  complited my requirment. so how can i do this with mysql query?

And my field type is **utf8_general_ci**

Thank you.

Comment: What is your database and table Collation?

Comment: @BikramPahi my table collection is latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: and databse collectio is ut8_generel_ci